# Alternative to 'coll.CountDocuments' function on Mongodb in golang. (Aggregation Pipeline)

Tags: database, mongodb, go, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**As you can see I am calling the "coll.CountDocuments" functions multiples times. What I want is to write the code without calling the "coll.CountDocuments" function multiple times by aggregating all the filters into a single query.**

```
func NoOfDocumentsInfo(DB string, col string, filters ...bson.D) ([]int64, error) {
    if nil == dbInstance {
      if nil == GetDBInstance() {
        logger.Error("Not connecting to DB")
    err := errors.New("DB connection error")
    return nil, err
  }
}

logger.Debugf("%s %s", DB, col)

coll := dbInstance.Database(DB).Collection(col)

counts := make([]int64, len(filters))
for i, filter := range filters {
  count, err := coll.CountDocuments(context.TODO(), filter)
  if err != nil {
    logger.Fatal(err)
    return nil, err
  }

  counts[i] = count
}

return counts, nil
}
```

**I have tried to used aggragation pipeline but "cur" and "result" is giving null output.**

```
`func NoOfDocumentsInfo(DB string, col string, filters ...bson.D) ([]int64, error) {
if dbInstance == nil {
  if GetDBInstance() == nil {
    logger.Error("Not connecting to DB")
    err := errors.New("DB connection error")
    return nil, err
  }
}

logger.Debugf("%s %s", DB, col)

coll := dbInstance.Database(DB).Collection(col)

pipeline := make([]bson.M, 0, len(filters)+2)
pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"$or": filters}})
pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"$group": bson.M{"_id": nil, "count": bson.M{"$sum": 1}}})
pipeline = append(pipeline, bson.M{"$group": bson.M{"_id": nil, "count": bson.M{"$first": "$count"}}})

var result struct {
  Count int64 `bson:"count"`
}

cur, err := coll.Aggregate(context.TODO(), pipeline)
if err != nil {
  logger.Fatal(err)
  return nil, err
}

logger.Debugf("cur: %+v", cur)
err = cur.Decode(&result)
logger.Debugf("result: %+v, err: %v", result, err)
if err != nil {
logger.Fatal(err)
return nil, err
}

return []int64{result.Count}, nil
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach would be the one that I'm going to share here. Let's start with the code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

var (
    dbInstance *mongo.Client
    ctx        context.Context
    cancel     context.CancelFunc
)

func NoOfDocumentsInfo(client *mongo.Client, DB string, col string, filters bson.A) (int64, error) {
    coll := client.Database(DB).Collection(col)
    myFilters := bson.D{
        bson.E{
            Key:   "$and",
            Value: filters,
        },
    }

    counts, err := coll.CountDocuments(ctx, myFilters)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return counts, nil
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    // set MongoDB connection
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017")
    mongoClient, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer mongoClient.Disconnect(ctx)

    // query with filters
    numDocs, err := NoOfDocumentsInfo(mongoClient, "demodb", "myCollection", bson.A{
        bson.D{bson.E{Key: "Name", Value: bson.D{bson.E{Key: "$eq", Value: "John Doe"}}}},
        bson.D{bson.E{Key: "Song", Value: bson.D{bson.E{Key: "$eq", Value: "White Roses"}}}},
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("num docs:", numDocs)
}
```

Let's see the relevant changes applied to the code:

- Expect a parameter called `filters` of type `bson.A` which is the type for the `array` in the MongoDB environment.
- Build the `myFilters` variable which is of type `bson.D` (slice) with the following single item (`bson.E`) in this way:

  - The `Key` is the logical operator
  - The `Value` is the array passed into the function
- Build the array to pass to the function with all of the needed filters (e.g. two equal conditions: one on the `Name` key and the other on the `Song`).

Finally, I also did some improvements on how you've opened the MongoDB connection and how you've released the allocated resources.
Let me know if this solves your issue, thanks!